# Laravel 5.5 customizing collection first() method

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a collection with values

```
$collection = [{
              "date": "2018-02-14",
              "time": "08:00:00"
               },{
              "date": "2018-02-15",
              "time": "08:00:00"
              },{
              "date": "2018-02-16",
              "time": "08:00:00"
              }]
```

I need to return the result as From: first() to last() of the collection in the format (2018-02-14 08:00:00 to 2018-02-16 08:00:00). I tried with using

```
$collection->first() and $collection->last()
```

How can i customize the result to required format?

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with converting each object to a Carbon object for easy date manipulation, then sort the collection and print a formatted string with the first and last items:

```
$sorted = $collection->map(function ($item) {
    return Carbon::parse($item->date . ' ' . $item->time);
})->sort();

$range = sprintf('From: %s to %s', $sorted->first()->toDateTimeString(), $sorted->last()->toDateTimeString());
```